# WordPress keeps autoplaying my Youtube-Links no matter what I write

Tags: api, embed, youtube, video-player

WordPress (with the LayerSlider plugin) keeps autoplaying my video no matter what code I use.

Here's the embed-Link for the video: `<iframe width="840" height="473" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ZoKYl6U388A" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

And here's how I changed it:

```
<iframe width="840" height="473" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ZoKYl6U388A?autoplay=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I tried both "?autoplay=0" and "autoplay="0" after the link.

Is there any specific way I have to embed the video for it not to play automatically?

Comment: Sorry but we can't help you with third party plugins here. Please ask at the plugin support.

Comment: 3rd party services would be more accurate, but I believe this is on topic since embedding Youtube videos is something Core supports. It is more of a user problem rather than a developer problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you know you can just copy paste a youtube URL onto its own line and it transforms into a video player auto-magically via **oembed**? There's no need for embed codes/shortcodes/plugins

Simply create a blank line, and take the address of the youtube video and paste it into the editor:

[image: oembed gif courtesy of clickwp]

These youtube videos should not play automatically

WordPress will pick up any URL for Youtube on a line by itself and convert it into a Video player automatically via OEmbed, the same is true of other services such as soundcloud, instagram, vimeo, flickr, tweets etc etc

Comment: Nice demonstration *ps: found your funny video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JmA2ClUvUY) for those who are curious* ;-)

Comment: well.. that was easier than expected. Thanks a lot.